# Background image - Responsive issue CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using `bootstrap` and I have a background image. It was set by CSS to implement basically a kind of parallax. 
Everything is ok, but the image dimension is `4066 x 4066` so I set the size as `background-size: 36%`. The problem is with the responsive view: on a phone it looks so small. Any idea how to fix this issue?

You can take a look my code below:

```
#home{
  background-size: 36% !important;
  background-position: 50% 26% !important;
  background: url('/assets/img/light_green2_home.png')  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 520px;
}
```

Comment: use @media css for it

Comment: or try using min-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (for screens smaller than 600px):

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

     #home{
       background-size: 50% !important;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for implementing a responsive background image.
Consider using `max-width` on a media query set to adjust the `background-size: "some percentage"`. I recommend using `background-size:cover` for the original image, which will ensure that your image fills the element without overlaps or "underlaps".

```
#home {
  background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (max-width: "some number"px) {
  #home {
    background-size: 60%;
  }
}
```

Some reading about CSS Media Queries [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

I would recommend against targeting a specific device size, but rather, set the `max-width` to the point when it just starts looking too small.